# посчитать количество checkbox на панели

Tags: c#

int count = (panel_admin_vivod.Controls as CheckBox).Count
получаю ошибку
Как отобрать именно checkbox c панели

Comment: В цикле по всем элементам панели и каждую сравнивать на CheckBox?

Comment: Вы как-то от обратного идете. Вы должны *знать* сколько у вас контролов и управлять ими вручную (иметь ссылку на каждый), а не считать их (они же не сами возникают?)

Comment: Согласен! Это же коллекция и ее надо всю перебрать поэлементно

Comment: Мне нужно знать количество для того чтобы знать какая строка и связать textbox -ы c выбранным checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Получить все элементы определенного типа можно к примеру через LINQ:

```
var items = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

Но соглашусь с комментаторами, лучше создавать элементы и иметь уже определенную коллекцию, а не загружать их из формы и только потом работать.